# How to draw bounding boxes to make comparisons?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, model-evaluation, object-detection

I have a whole bunch of prediction bounding boxes for my test images. What is the best way to draw the bounding boxes so that I can use it to compare across different models?

For example, for each image, I draw only the bounding box with the max IOU, or max confidence score etc.

Several other models I've used have chosen to draw all bounding boxes above a certain confidence score but I don't know if this'll allow me to compare across different models and whether it allows me to compare within the current model (i.e. which images in the current model are doing better, which are doing badly).

Comment: This is a very good question.